# one global var with two values within 1 module after import

Tags: python, function, import, subprocess, call

I have this multiload module that multiprocess.Popen two other modules. Module1 has to call a function in module2 and change a (for module2 global) var. But after that call there live two different values of that var in module2. This beginner is puzzled... (-;

```
## module multiload.py

from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

t=1
Popen(['python3', 'module2.py'])
sleep(t)
Popen(['python3', 'module1.py'])
sleep(t)
```

```
## module module1.py

import time
print("to load")
import module2
print("loaded")

i=0
while True:
    module2.changeVar(i)
    print("module1",i)
    print("module2.PLvar",module2.PLvar)
    i+=1
    time.sleep(3)
```

```
## module module2.py

import time

PLvar = 6

def changeVar(v):
    global PLvar
    PLvar = v
    print("changeVar m2",PLvar)  # this PLvar is changing with the loop in module1

def main():
    while True:
        global PLvar
        print ("while m2",PLvar) # this PLvar is stuck at 6 (as assigned in line 3)
        time.sleep(3)

print("module2",__name__)
if (__name__=="__main__"):
    print("module 2 main started")
    main()
```

Comment: No need to put everything in a single block code, you can put 3 block codes and use `# ` in fornt od the filename as title.

Comment: You are running two separate instances of python and each will read the use the base definition of `module2.py`. You might want to check out the `pickle` module for potentially reading and writing data that might be loaded/written by separate executions of python.  Alternatively, you might look at the `multiprocessing` package for ways to execute your two code paths in the same python context and using a global variable perhaps guarded by `lock()` to share a context.